# If a double condition is met, then add to a specific dictionary

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I'm trying to create a code that will allow me to check if columns A and C both matches "Car" and "Red". If yes, I want to fill my existing `DicoRedCar` with the Brand of the Car as item, and Price as Key here is my code :

```
Sub Dicofill()
    Dim DicoRedCar As Object
    Set DicoRedCar = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim Startcell As Range 
    Set Startcell = Data.Range("A1") 
    i = i + 1 

    If Startcell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "Car" And Startcell.Offset(i, 2).Value = "Red" Then 
        DicoRedCar.Add Startcell.Offset(i, 0).Value, Startcell.Offset(i, 1).Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Column 1 is vehicle type, column 2 brand of the car, column 3 Color of the car, Column 6 Price of the car.

But it does not feed the Dico. I know that on range A24 I have a red car appearing, but nothing happens. I tried to check with a MsgBox for the Then Statement but it gave me nothing. I tried this but nothing happened:

```
If Startcell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "Car" And Startcell.Offset(i, 2).Value = "Red" Then
    Msgbox("found a Red Car")
End If
```

So I think that the blocking point came first from my "If...Then" statements

[image: Image of my table]

Comment: You don't appear to be looping. The above code is only ever going to check row 2.

Comment: Does `Data` refer to the range you want to scan down, or is it the Sheet reference?

Comment: is i defined somewhere else, it's not passed in and its not initialized with a value?  It doesn't look like a loop to me, and typically you will increment after your code so it happens just before the condition is checked again.

Comment: will columns A and C always be the same length (one not missing data) and is the starting row known?  Should come together pretty quickly once this is known.

Comment: data refer to my sheet

Answer (score 0):

This is something that may get you started:

```
Sub Dicofill()

    Dim DicoRedCar As Object
    Dim Startcell   As Range
    Dim myCell      As Range

    Set DicoRedCar = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set Startcell = Range("A1")

    For Each myCell In Range("A1:A10")
        If myCell.Offset(0, 1) = "Car" And myCell.Offset(0, 2) = "Red" Then
            'it is a good idea to check whether the key exists before adding it:
            DicoRedCar.Add myCell.Offset(0, 1), myCell.Offset(0, 4)
        End If
    Next myCell

End Sub
```

It loops through the Range("A1:A10") and it checks column `B` for "Car" and column `C` for "Red". If they are found column `B` is added to the dictionary `DicoRedCar` as Key and column `E` is the value.

As a next step, consider checking whether a key exists in the dictionary, before adding it, because it will give you an error. This is how to do it:

```
dict.Exists(Key)
e.g. If DicoRedCar.Exists(myCell.Offset(0,1)) Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Data` is a reference to a sheet.. the following will scan down column A and stop when it reaches the first empty cell:

```
Sub Dicofill()
Dim DicoRedCar As Object
Set DicoRedCar = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim Startcell As Range

Set Startcell = Data.Range("A1")
Do Until Startcell.Offset(i + 1, 0).Value = ""
    i = i + 1
    If Startcell.Offset(i, 0).Value = "Car" And Startcell.Offset(i, 2).Value = "Red" Then
        DicoRedCar.Add Startcell.Offset(i, 0).Value, Startcell.Offset(i, 1).Value
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: i tried to do so but i have :  Run time error 457 This key is already associated with an element of this collection. :/

Comment: Then you've got two red cars? @Vityata covers this towards the end of their answer.